# 'HTTPResponse' object is not callable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, httpresponse

Im trying to open a file using python,for storing the article extracted from url.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  

url = "http://www.thedrum.com/news/2015/07/29/mankind-must-get-ahead-technical-development-states-phds-mark-holden-following"
openfile = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(openfile)

  
f = open("test1.txt", "w")
  

for data in soup.find_all("p"):
    sum1 = data.get_text()
    f.writelines(sum1)
  
f.close()
```

But it shows the `TypeError: 'HTTPResponse' object is not callable`pointing to `f = open("test1.txt", "w")`
How do I solve this?

Comment: Try changing the variable name from `sum` to something else; I suspect you are overwriting the [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).

Comment: @msbit Thanks for pointing out, but still the same error is shown.

Comment: could you please share your `soup variable` ?

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow I have edited with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the soup object from the html content (that you get from the read function), not the response object

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as r, open("test1.txt", "w") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.read().decode('utf-8'))
    for data in soup.find_all("p"):
        sum1 = data.get_text()
        f.writelines(sum1)
```

Comment: i tested your code but for some reasons it is not working but when i changed this line `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.read().decode('utf-8'))` to `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.read().decode('utf-8'),features="lxml")`  it worked perfectly may be i am using an other version ?

Comment: Works fine, also without `decode()`, so may check if version is up to date. Just one point cause while working with u-tf8 you may use `open("test1.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8')`.

Comment: @Thi Maybe you need to install html5lib?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks, it worked. Actually I was trying the code in Jupytr NB and there itsnt working...it shows the same error. When I tried the code saved in .py file, it worked. Thanks others also for the suggestions. :)